# Delay Information in an Array on VPython

Tags: python, arrays, function, delay, vpython

I am working on a project in which I am storing angle values into an array temporarily, using them in a visual simulation, then deleting the values once the display is updated.

I am attempting to create an identical array of the same values, however I want them delayed by a certain amount (I would like the amount to be variable). How would I go about doing this? I have considered zero padding the array at the beginning, however numpy zero padding does not allow appending values.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the % modulo operator for the variable delay in a vpython program. In a vpython program you typically have a simulation loop that runs forever at a given frame rate.

```
delay = 30     # configurable delay
cnt = 0
while True:
    rate(30)   # vpython simulation runs at 30 frames per second (fps)
    cnt += 1
    if cnt % delay == 0:      # delay one second  (delay/30fps = 1 second)
        # do what you want with your array when the delay time has been reached.
    else:
        # do something else
```

John